# How to write a switch statement, specifically a default statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm a beginner learning Java, and my teacher gave me this question:

> Write a switch statement which assigns a value to char grade based on
> the value of int variable score.
>
> - A score between 0 and 4 inclusive gets an 'F'.
> - A score of 5 or 6 gets a 'D'
> - A score of 7 gets a 'C'
> - A score of 8 gets a 'B'
> - A score of 9 or 10 gets an 'A'
>
> Any other score gets an 'X'.
>
> No other code than the switch statement itself should be included.

Here's what I wrote:

```
switch (grade) {
case 'A':
    break;
case 'B':
    break;
case 'C':
    break;
case 'D':
    break;
case 'F':
    break;
case 'X': 

 break;
}
```

After running it on the website, I found that all cases worked except 'X'. So I tried:

```
default: grade = 'X'
```

But that also did not work.
How can I add 'X' as a default for this switch statement, and what can help me prevent myself from making this mistake again?

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote that switch, the purpose is to GIVE a value to `grade`, here you are using that value, that isn't at all what is asked

Comment: You need to switch on score, not on grade. And then assign something to grade.

Comment: wouldnt the cases be like case 0: case1: case2: case 3: case 4: grade = "F"; break;

Answer (score 0):

The switch may be used the other way, `score > grade` and not `grade > ...` as you did

```
static char scoreToGrade(int score) {
    switch (score) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return 'F';
        case 5:
        case 6:
            return 'D';
        case 7:
            return 'C';
        case 8:
            return 'B';
        case 9:
        case 10:
            return 'A';
        default:
            return 'X';
    }
}
```

Or with the other switch expression

```
static char scoreToGrade(int score) {
    return switch (score) {
        case 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 -> 'F';
        case 5, 6 -> 'D';
        case 7 -> 'C';
        case 8 -> 'B';
        case 9, 10 -> 'A';
        default -> 'X';
    };
}
```

Then call

```
char grade = scoreToGrade(4);
char grade = scoreToGrade(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Reading the requirement, you should rethink what is the purpose of the question. The `switch` statement shouldn't use the `grade` as a parameter, but the `score`. Before executing the function, you only know the score: the **input** is the *score*, and the **output** of your function is the *grade*. Using the `score` in the case conditions and return from there the `grades`. As the code executes sequentially, the last statement should be [default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), returning the `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to explain this as easy as possible.

You want to **check** the score to **assign** a grade.

Switch takes a variable, in your case you placed grade, and **checks** if it matches with the **cases**, in case the grade is **equal** to A, to B,C...
If I explained it well, the first problem should be easy to see, you are **checking** the variable your are trying to **assign**.
You don't have a value for grade at the start, so its imposible to check a condition.
So you should **check** score (placing it on the switch), and **assign** grade inside the cases.

```
String grade; //no values
int score=4; //The variable we want to check
switch (score) {
        case 0:
            grade = "F";
            break;
        case 1:
            grade = "F";
            break;
        case 2:
            grade = "F";
            break;
        case 3:
            grade = "F";
            break;
        case 4:
            grade = "F";
            break;
        case 5:
            grade = "D";
            break;
        case 6:
            grade = "D";
            break;
        case 7:
            grade = "C";
            break;
        case 8:
            grade = "B";
            break;
        case 9:
        case 10:
            grade = "A";
            break;
        default:
            grade = "X";
    }
```

You can imagine it like a series of if checking for equality:

```
if(score==0){
    grade="F";
}
if(score == 1){
    grade="F";
}
if(score == 2){
    grade="F";
}
if(score == 3){
    grade="F";
}
if(score == 4){
    grade="F";
}
if(score == 5){
    grade="D";
}
if(score == 6){
    grade="D";
}
//and so on
```

(It would more precise to use else if, but this is an example trying to make it as easy as possible, also doesn't cover all switch functionality, but you can get an idea of what I mean with **checking** and **assigning**).

At the end, your grade variable will have a value, cause you assigned it in the switch cases.

You can improve that switch, getting rid of the breaks on the firs 4 cases, so it will work like a "cascade", jumping to the next case until it finds a break:

```
  String grade; //no values
    int score=4 //The variable we want to check
    switch (score) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                grade = "F";
                break;
            case 5:
                grade = "D";
                break;
            case 6:
                grade = "D";
                break;
            case 7:
                grade = "C";
                break;
            case 8:
                grade = "B";
                break;
            case 9:
            case 10:
                grade = "A";
                break;
            default:
                grade = "X";
        }
```